# Alternative to using double backslash in math environments?

Tags: math-mode, environments, mathjax

I have a (frustrating) toolchain problem involving some software that behaves unexpectedly with respect to `\\`.  It's part of a toolchain I'm using to produce HTML with MathJax. The problem causes expressions such as

```
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}
```

to be formatted incorrectly, as if `\\` were only `\`. Some experimentation shows that `\\\\` works, which clearly implies some kind of (mis)behavior involving escape characters, but I can't change the software in question and I don't want to write `\\\\` because that's not standard for other LaTeX and MathJax systems. Thankfully, the behavior *only* seems to affect double backslashes and not instances of single backslashes (i.e., things like `\sigma` are not affected), which suggests I could deal with it by substituting something else for `\\`. This leads to the following question:

**Is there a command that is equivalent to `\\` (but is not typed `\\`) in math environments?**

Note: I cannot insert a filter between my input and the tool doing this (it's all part of a single software system) so I can't do something like write a filter that would replace `\\` in the user's input with `\\\\` before passing it on.

Additional note added on 2021-09-08 after original posting: the reason I care about finding a valid LaTeX/TeX alternative – and hence posting here – is because I use LaTeX in other contexts, and would like to maintain input compatibility.

Comment: `\newline` works in MathJax (at least on Math.SE), but obviously not in LaTeX. Anyway, this is off-topic here.

Comment: @egreg How is this possibly off topic here? The question is about LaTeX/TeX math syntax. The MathJax info is for context, but I could just as easily rephrase it to ask only about math syntax. (And if I did, someone would ask me "why do you need to find something other than double backslash?", which is why I wrote all the context right up front.)

Comment: @mhucka not really (for example `\tabularnewline` works in latex, your question is just about what works in mathjax,

Comment: Maybe I went too far with context. Perhaps it would help if I explained that the reason I care to find valid LaTeX syntax is because I _also_ use LaTeX ...

Comment: you should be able to define \tabularnewline as a macro expanding to `\\ ` in your mathjax setup

Comment: it looks like you could also use `\cr`  if you never use `\\[10pt]` mathjax lists that as supported

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just tried it and `\cr` works :-).  Will do some more testing, but preliminarily this appears to solve the problem. Thank you!